# Should I use Git Branch for the extra logging code for a nasty production-only bug?

Tags: git, git-branch, error-logging

I have a live web site where a bug is manifesting only in PROD.  I was thinking that rather than implement some logging on my prod branch I'd make a special short-lived logging branch and check that out into PROD having first tested it in my staging server.  Then, I can switch back to the main trunk branch once I troubleshooted the issue.

I realize that testing in PROD is wrong but we cannot reproduce this bug in the staging server.  Am I missing an approach or, can you comment on the danger of pulling a branch (which is not very divergent from trunk) into production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to branch out of PROD into a short-lived testing branch. You should be branching out at the commit/tag where you see the issue.

Use this branch to make any changes and fix the issue. After verifying your FIX on the Staging Server, merge the changes back into PROD branch.

```
git checkout PROD
git branch my_short_lived_branch
<DEPLOY short_lived_branch on Staging Server to confirm issue is reproducible>
<DEBUG and FIX the issue>
<DEPLOY and confirm the FIX>
git checkout PROD
git merge --no-ff my_short_lived_branch
<DEPLOY on Staging server and confirm the issue is fixed>
<IF the issue is fixed, deploy the changes to your production server>
```

Comment: Now if this bug is only in PROD and I don't see it in staging server, as disgusting as it sounds, how hard should I be avoiding making live changes in PROD if I can't reproduce it.    Also, I want to note, this is an ecommerce site where visible artifacts are being shown to users but the underlying system seems to be working... i'm just trying to figure out what conjunction of data/events is causing an "erroneous" error message to be shown to users.

Comment: I believe it is your OR the owner's call on what artifacts are acceptable in a Production environment and the overall impact. I know we're kind of deviating from the original question, but just to give you some pointers - you could try logging crucial events to some logger for your web site/service, and try to get the chain of events causing the artifact. That might get you closer to fixing the issue. You could also compare the logs between the staging and the PROD environment if it helps.